# Docker desktop about "ping" command

Tags: docker, ping

I can not use ping command when I enter into my container. What should I do?
I'm using the Docker Desktop, and I use "docker -d --name tomcat01 tomcat" to build the container.
It seems that all network command dont work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9shJ.png)

Comment: did you try to install them? what's the linux distro? can you use the packet manager to install those missing binaries?

Comment: Why do you need to "enter into your container"?  Why do you need to send ICMP packets at all?  Can you [edit] the question to replace the image link with a [mcve]?